# converting jira json string to java object

Tags: java, json, jira

How can i convert jira json string to java object i want to get the issue details

```
{
  "expand": "schema,names",
  "startAt": 0,
  "maxResults": 50,
  "total": 1,
  "issues": [
    {
      "expand": "editmeta,renderedFields,transitions,changelog,operations",
      "id": "10000",
      "self": "http://jira.com/rest/api/2/issue/10000",
      "key": "APPANLYTIX-1",
      "fields": {},
        "issuetype": {},
        "votes": {},
        "resolution": null,
        "fixVersions": [{}],
        "resolutiondate": null,
        "timespent": null,
        "reporter": {
          "avatarUrls": {},
          "displayName": "yyyy Dev",
          "active": true
        },
        "subtasks": [],
        "status": {},
        "labels": [],
        "workratio": 0,
        "assignee": {
          "avatarUrls": {},
          "displayName": "",
          "active": true
        },
        "project": {
          "name": "",
          "avatarUrls": { }
        },
        "versions": [{}],
        "environment": "windows",
        "timeestimate": 28800,
        "aggregateprogress": {},
        "lastViewed": "2013-07-18T04:39:52.596+0000",
        "components": [ ],
        "timeoriginalestimate": 28800,
        "aggregatetimespent": null
    }
  ]
}
```

Most of the examples I refereed are using java bean for setting the variables,is there any API for doing this?

Comment: Do you want to generate the object class code or you want to bind that json to an existing java class?

Comment: i actually want to bind it to a java class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your class has a structure like the json you've showed you can use use the [gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) library to bind it to the class.

Answer (score 1):

I handle this problem another third party library, you can download this code. And Edit as your scenario.

You should only edit SimpleConfigurationProvider this java class. 
You have to specify your privateKey, AccessToken and baseUrl. And then jiraClient Authentication you can receive project and issue thanks to under code block

As a result you can convert java class object as ArrayList and   JiraProject[]

https://github.com/symphonyoss/bot-jira

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    JiraOauthClient jiraClient = new JiraOauthClient(new SimpleConfigurationProvider());
    JiraProject[] projects = jiraClient.getAllProjects();

    for (JiraProject project : projects) {
        if (project.getKey().equals("UOCM")) {
            ArrayList<JiraIssue> issues = jiraClient.getIssuesForProject(project);

            for (JiraIssue issue : issues) {
                System.out.println(issue.getId());
                 ///.....
            }
        }
    }
}
```